# Using Websphere MQ for transferring messages between two machines

Tags: ibm-mq

I have being trying to transfer a message between two host. I followed  [Jump start WebSphere MQ development on Linux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0705_salkosuo/0705_salkosuo.html) article, It's work fine with two queue manager in single machine.

Here I created one local queue, one transmission queue and one remote queue and also create the sender , receiver and SVRCONN channel in both queue manager. I can transfer the message between two queue manager.

But I try this with two host, when I try to start the channel it doesn't work.

Much appreciated if anyone could help me with this issue Or let me know if more clarification on my question is required.

Comment: The SVRCONN wasn't necessary for connecting two queue managers together. you don't mention starting a listener. Can you say a little more about exactly what you did to send the messages when it worked. There should be little difference when going from two queue managers on one machine to two machine, except that the CONNAME field will need a different IP address or hostname in it. I'm concerned that maybe you didn't send the message by the channels when your putting application was on the same machine as the target/remote queue manager.

Comment: If the channel failed to start with an error, please add the details to your question. You will find the error in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG file. You may want to check this file on both queue manages for channel error messages.

Comment: Thank you all , I did a mistake I connected different network in the two machines. Now I solve this problem with connecting the two machines in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a starter here:

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp0021.pdf
The part which is relevant to your case starts at page 46 of the MQ Series Red Book.

At the very least you should enroll to a CBT course and get MQ training.